# How to optimize Mysql Query that has 2 Inner Joins with Distinct? ( InnoDB )

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a query which I use InnoDB storage engine.

I want to optimize it. It takes too much time to execute. I have 5 million data in my database. Now it takes 250 seconds to execute.

```
INSERT INTO dynamicgroups (adressid) 

    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT(addressid) FROM (
        SELECT cluster_0.addressid FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT addressid FROM (
                SELECT group_all.addressid FROM (
                    SELECT g.addressid FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g 
                        INNER JOIN table2.emaildata f_0
                               ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
                        WHERE  (f_0.birthday > date(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 18 MONTH))
                            AND f_0.birthday < CURDATE() )
                ) group_all
            ) AS groups

        ) AS cluster_0

        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT DISTINCT addressid FROM (
                SELECT group_all.addressid FROM (
                    SELECT g.addressid FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g 
                        INNER JOIN table2.emaildata f_0
                               ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
                        WHERE  (marriage_date = ''
                             OR marriage_date = '1900-01-01'
                             OR marriage_date = '0000-00-00' )
                ) group_all
            ) AS groups
        ) AS cluster_1 ON cluster_1.addressid = cluster_0.addressid

        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT DISTINCT addressid FROM (
                SELECT group_all.addressid FROM (
                    SELECT g.addressid FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g 
                        INNER JOIN table2.emaildata f_0
                                ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
                        WHERE  (f_0.city = '34' )
                ) group_all
            ) AS groups
        ) AS cluster_2 ON cluster_2.addressid = cluster_1.addressid 
    ) AS t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries all seem to be variations of this query:

```
SELECT g.addressid
FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g INNER JOIN
     table2.emaildata f_0
     ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
WHERE  (f_0.birthday > date(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND f_0.birthday < CURDATE() )
```

I would suggest approaching this using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT g.addressid
FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g INNER JOIN
     table2.emaildata f_0
     ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
GROUP BY g.addressid
HAVING SUM(f_0.birthday > date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND f_0.birthday < CURDATE() ) > 0 AND
       SUM(marriage_date = '' OR marriage_date = '1900-01-01'  OR marriage_date = '0000-00-00' ) > 0 AND
       SUM(f_0.city = '34' ) > 0;
```

Depending on the volume of data, filtering before the `group by` can also help:

```
SELECT g.addressid
FROM table2.635_emadresmgroups g INNER JOIN
     table2.emaildata f_0
     ON f_0.addressid = g.addressid
WHERE (f_0.birthday > date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND f_0.birthday < CURDATE() ) OR
      (marriage_date = ''  OR marriage_date = '1900-01-01' OR marriage_date = '0000-00-00' ) OR
      (f_0.city = '34' )
GROUP BY g.addressid
HAVING SUM(f_0.birthday > date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND f_0.birthday < CURDATE() ) > 0 AND
       SUM(marriage_date = '' OR marriage_date = '1900-01-01'  OR marriage_date = '0000-00-00' ) > 0 AND
       SUM(f_0.city = '34' ) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the EXPLAIN operator isn't implemented as well as others.. I'd suggest you use it for your query.

After that you can analyse what the result that EXPLAIN give and decide which columns should be indexed.

For more information I'd suggest viewing these sources:

[MySQL syntax: EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

[MySQL using: EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Furthermore, the last 2 selects appear to be very similar, maybe you can make a temporary table or a view out of these, so that you don't have to run the entire select twice?

Answer (score 0):

`marriage_date` -- Make it NULLable and use NULL instead of '', etc.  That will avoid an inefficient `OR` and *might* lead to usability of an `INDEX`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can assess the current indexes.

What version are you running?  Until *very* recently this construct was *very* inefficient:

```
FROM ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

The workaround was to put the subqueries into tmp tables and add an `INDEX`.

This *may* help in your case, since you seem to be using the `JOINs` for filtering:  Turn `JOIN ( SELECT ... )` into `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )`.

Please describe, in English, what the query is trying to do.

Another approach, building on Gordon's suggestion of having a common SELECT:  Put that common SELECT into a TEMPORARY table; add index(es), then query from it.